# How does split work here?

Tags: perl

```
$string = 'a=1;b=2';
use Data::Dumper;
@array = split("; ?", $string);
print Dumper(\@array);
```

output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'a=1',
          'b=2'
        ];
```

Anyone knows how `"; ?"` work here?It's not regex, but works quite like regex,so I don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it means "semicolon followed by optional space (just one or zero)".

> It's not regex, but works quite like regex,so I don't understand.

The pattern parameter to split is always treated as a regular expression (would be better to not use a string, though). The only exception is the "single space", which is taken to mean "split on whitespace"

Comment: But it's not regex,it's just string.

Comment: Do you mean `" "` is the same as `/\s+/`?

Comment: Yes, almost: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html. "A split on /\s+/ is like a split(' ') except that any leading whitespace produces a null first field."

Comment: @asker: No, `" "` is the same as `/\s+/` followed by a `shift()` on the return array before return if the first resulting field would be null. That way it acts like awk and disregards any leading whitespace on the line. And the argument to `split` **is indeed** a regex, in all but two cases (the null string arguably being the other). Haven't you read the entry for `split` in the *perlfunc(1)* manpage?

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `split` is a *regex*. So I'd rather write `split /; ?/, $string;`.
When you use a string for the first parameter, it just means the regex can vary and has to be compiled anew each time the split is run. See `perldoc -f split` for details.

The regex could be read; *the character ";" optionally followed by a space*. See perlretut and perlreref for details.

Comment: I'd write it `/ ; \h* /x` myself.  Maybe.

Comment: Optionally followed, not eventually followed.

Comment: My bad. I'm French, and I would have said "éventuellement" in French, hence my mistake.

Comment: Edited to correct "eventually followed" to "optionally followed".

Answer (score 0):

A semicolon (the ;) followed by an optional (the ?) space (the ).